# How to split data into training and testing set only using numpy not pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I'm doing CNN and trying split my data into training and testing datasets. After splitting, I want to use `sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler` to **scale my testing data with the parameters of training data**.

So before scaling, I need to split the data. I'm gonna use `sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split`, but to use that method I have to convert my data into a `pandas.DataFrame`. Since my data are for CNN, their lengths don't meet the requirements of a DataFrame

```py
print(x.shape, delta.shape, z.shape, y.shape, non_spatial_data.shape, p.shape, g.shape)
# (15000, 175) (15000, 175) (15000, 175) (15000, 1225) (15000, 264) (15000, 175) (15000, 175)
```

The above are the sizes of my data after being flattened. 15000 is the sample size.
You can see the lengths of different data are different, which makes me unable to convert them into DataFrame. So how can I do the splitting only using numpy? Or is there any other method to do the whole **splitting and scaling** process?

PS: The data I am using for CNN are not really images. They are some data with spatial properties.

Comment: can you provide input data and test size percentage?

Comment: @lemon Maybe I'd like to use 20% for testing?

Comment: @lemon Actually I'd like to add more data later to be like half a million. At that moment, I will just use 2%.

Comment: @lemon is that you are asking the ratio of test data? Or you need other more information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's working example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])
c = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10])

n = 0.2

spl = None
for arr in [a, b, c]:
    if spl is None:
        rand_ind = np.random.choice(range(len(arr)), len(arr))
        spl, remaining = np.split(rand_ind, [int(n * len(rand_ind))])
    print([arr[i] for i in spl])
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite follow your answer. What is _n_ for? In my understanding, _n_ is for splitting into n equal arrays and then I can group some of them into training set while the other can be grouped into testing set. Besides this, I find that there are maybe some indices of the same value in list _ind_. How can I fix it?

Comment: Sorry, I've updated the code, the idea is to split arrays in the same uniform ways, by  "restoring" random seed (so it's still random but stays same for all arrays :-) )

Comment: Thanks, I get your idea. But I still have some questions. Does `np.array(reader)` indicate the parameter `arr`? And is there anything missing in the second argument of `np.split`?

Comment: Sorry I was copypasting from my jupyter notebook with some sample data and forgot to change it accordingly, updated now

Comment: Thanks for your reply. After some tests, I find `spl, remaining = np.split(range(len(arr)), [int(n * len(ind))])` may be more correct. Then I also think that maybe the code doesn't need `ind`, because `spl` is only related to `len(ind)` which is the same as `len(arr)`. Is`ind` meant to randomize the code? But after I do some tests, I find that if I delete `np.random.seed(1)`, the function still gives me the first 2 elemets of the array everytime (say `len(arr)` is 10 and `n` is 0.2).

Comment: Hi, I've got one thought. I don't know if there is also a `seed` function in `sklearn`. If so, maybe I can "randomly" split and scale each data seperately. At last, just group them together.

Comment: You're right maybe I am overthinking, I've pushed another example now, the idea is to "store" index of splitted items from the first array, and the to apply it to the other arrays. Please note, you might need to restart jupyter (if you use one) after playing with random.seed (I got a liittle bit stuck with that)

Comment: Thank you! It's much better! But I think there might be still one issue. It's that the first two elements of `rand_int` may get the same. So I've got another idea to chage it a little bit. I will do some changes through editing.

Comment: For "resorted", I mean "rearranged". Sorry for the language mistake.

Answer (score 1):

From [Mr. svfat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71939178/18878180), I find that I am overthinking. And my question has made Mr. svfat overthink, too. In summary, to split data, we just need to randomly pick a fixed ratio of the indices and apply them to slice each data.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).